# Naive Question About Interpreting a Set Notation

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory, soft-question

> I was reading Folland's real analysis and notice that there is one very basic concept about the set notation usage yet I don't understand very well.
>
> In the bottom of page 22, Folland defines a *product $\sigma$-algebra* on $X$ to be the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the set
>   $$
> \{ \pi_{\alpha}^{-1}(E_\alpha) : E_\alpha \in \mathcal{M}_\alpha, \alpha \in A \}:=\Pi
> $$ 
>   where $\pi_{\alpha}: X \to X_\alpha$ is the coordinate maps and $X:=\prod_{\alpha \in A} X_\alpha$ and $\mathcal{M}_{\alpha}$ is the $\sigma$-algebra on $X_\alpha$ for each $\alpha$ and $A$ is the index set.

The thing I got confused is to interpret its (superficial) meaning of the set defined above based on the given form. Say $x \in \Pi$, does this means

$x$ has the form of $\pi_{\alpha}^{-1}(E_\alpha)$ where $E_{\alpha} \in \mathcal{M}_\alpha$ **AND** $\alpha \in A$?

If so, may I rewrite directly by saying
$$
\Pi =?= \bigcap_{\alpha \in A} \{\pi_{\alpha}^{-1}(E_\alpha) : E_\alpha \in \mathcal{M}_\alpha\}
$$

Any comment is appreciated.

Comment: It'd be a union, not an intersection. I read it as "There exists some $\alpha$ such that $x$ is of the form $\pi_\alpha^{-1}(E_\alpha)$ for some $E_\alpha\in\mathcal{M}_\alpha$."

Comment: Folland means $\Pi = \{\pi_\alpha^{-1}(E) \colon E \in \mathcal{M}_\alpha, \text{ where } \alpha \in A \}$.  That is, $\Pi$ is the collection of sets $\pi_\alpha^{-1}(E)$, where in the collection we consider every $E \in \mathcal{M}_\alpha$ for every index $\alpha$.

Comment: Yes you may rewrite it however you like even if it is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's more of a union. One could also say $$\Pi = \{A: \exists \alpha \in A: \exists E_\alpha \in \mathcal{M}_\alpha: A = \pi_{\alpha}^{-1}[E_\alpha] \}$$

which, if you like, could also be written as

$$\Pi = \bigcup_{\alpha \in A} \pi_{\alpha}^{-1}[\mathcal{M}_\alpha] $$

where $f^{-1}[\mathcal{A}]$ (for a family of sets in $Y$ and $f:X \to Y$ a function between sets) just means $\{f^{-1}[A]: A \in \mathcal{A} \}$.